# How bad are the last 11 dry years in a row?

Tags: time-series, probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, forecasting

**How bad are the last 11 dry years in a row?**

In the following graph there are 61 years of records of the annual energy that could be transformed in electricity using water-driven power plants in Chile:

[image: Graph 1]

In order to explain there is a trend of dry years, I am comparing that the last 11 years are below the average of the previous 50 years with records, but to give a sense of how bad it is, I would like to take the **probability of having these 11 years below the average in a row at the end just for chance** (expecting it to be very low, so it tell we have indeed a trend), but I don't know how to do it, since the time variable should have a meaning: the problem is somehow like having 11 tails in a row after 50 random previous results on 61 coin tosses, different of just counting 11 tails out of 61 tosses, but since the average change with each year, it is different from the coin example (which are there plenty of examples in Google).

Here you could find the table with the data: [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10eA-00KLqX2BXn-pqQmUJIjAl8A8Zeo1XLmbRWnUJhM/edit?usp=sharing), but I preferred as an answer, the explanation of how to get the mentioned probability than just the final number.

---

*What I have tried so far (added later)*

I have test the data visually with a [Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) by taking the data [Empirical Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) and its look its fit quite good:

[image: Empirical cumulative distribution]

So since it don't look skew, I think is a good assumption consider that there is a $50/50$ chance of being above or below the average. With this, the problem "looks" similar to having coin tosses, so the total amount of alternative results are $2^{61}$, and having $11$ results below the average **at the end** becomes a string of $\underbrace{2\cdot 2\cdots 2\cdot 2}_{50\,\text{times}}\cdot \underbrace{1 \cdot 1\cdots 1\cdot 1}_{11\,\text{times}}=2^{50}$ alternatives fitting the required pattern, so I could estimate the probability of having the shown results just by chance as:
$$ P\biggr(\text{the last 11 years below the average in a row}\biggr) = \frac{2^{50}}{2^{61}} = 0.0488 \%$$

Where I used that having exactly the average is a zero-measure point so it can be ignored.

But the issue in my line of thought, I think, is that the time variable is not considered, and the obtained probability thinking in coin tosses is valid for 11 heads (or tails) in a row independently of where the row is located, so having it exactly **at the end** could lead to a probability even lower.

So far, I think the result could be used as an upper bound for the real probability, but since I don't know nothing about stochastic time series, I would like to see if what I have done make any sense or not.

---

*Added later*

After the comment by @TickaJules I realize the complications: a change in the average could drop my assumptions since I have implicitly assumed the process is stationary.

But in the same line, if I compare the same statistics for the previous 50 years, which looks quite Normal/Gaussian, with the final 11 years were both the average and the standard deviation have decreased, they don't look Gaussian at all, and even when they are too few points to say something meaningful, the first graph kind of show a decreasing tendency, which is somehow supported but their cumulative distribution skewed to lower values:

[image: First 50 years]

[image: Final 11 years]

So I think that the previous calculated probability could still be a valid calculation considering it as a measuring a **probability of $\mathbf{99.95\%}$ chance that something structural have changed in the last 11 years compared with the previous 50 years**... or it is just too "cherry picking" as an assertion?

My arguments are:

- If I believe that nothing have change in the last 61 years, since the aggregated data looks Normal, then the procedure for taking the probability $p =  0.0488 \%$ is valid, so is far more probable that indeed something "bad" have happened - and ironically this dismissed the assumption that nothing have happened.
- And if I believe that something have change in the last 11 years, since these dry years in a row skewed the data to lower values, thinking in a moving average, the average now is lower making even harder to these years to be below it, but indeed it still happening. Since all the data is been considered in the analysis, I think is not skewed enough to say it have so much weight to lower values now, than it is more probable to have lower values than above the average, even when it is indeed what is happening so far, which somehow supports the hypothesis that something structural is different now. Following this argument, then the probability $p =  0.0488 \%$ is an upper bound for the "true probability", so considering all the years registered I have that at least with a probability of $99.95\%$ something structural have change on the final 11 years.

Does it make sense? or there are still something missing in what could be explaining these 11 dry years?

Comment: Hi, there are many possible ways to answer this based on what assumptions you choose to make.  This makes it a bit ambiguous for a math question.

Comment: @JairTaylor Could you elaborate about the assumptions you are thinking about?... Maybe I am not completely understanding what I am asking for, but my intention is based just on the available data, with the empirical distribution of those 61 samples, figure out the probability of having those 11 samples in a row that are below the average, or maybe below some fix value since I am comparing it with the average of the previous 50 samples instead of the overall average which change with each of the additional sample of the 11's row, as they are introduced as time passes in the time series.

Comment: Well, how do you find the empirical distribution for those samples?  You could assume a normal distribution, for example, or some other distribution. Or, you could take a bootstrapping approach and re-sample the previous 61 records.

Comment: You can assume that the history observations follow a normal distribution and get the estimated parameters, then calculate the posibility of case of interest. Or you can just resample the data based on the history observation, and note down the frequency of such or severer cases.

Comment: @JairTaylor I were thinking in make the [Empirical distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) by using the histogram. My problem is not the part of doing what is done as example from rows in coin tosses, my issue is how you treat the time variable related probability, I don't know nothing about stochastic time series and my intuition tells it change the problem compared with the coin tosses example

Comment: I think it's reasonable as a null hypothesis to assume that there's a "true average rate" (stationarity) that you can estimate using all your data so then being "below average" is about 1/2 (non-skewness), then you can work out the calculation as a math problem.  Also one could argue this assumption is at the root of all statistical evil.  There are alternative models: regress to find the rate through time, but that seems to need more assumptions, etc., to be explained and backed up.

Comment: @TickaJules Thanks for commenting. Indeed I have just realized I was implicitly assuming  that the process is stationary. I added a second view to the data, where indeed the first 50 years looks Gaussian with a fixed average, but the later 11 years looks something have change "visually"... I am not familiarized with tests to measure how probable is an structural change in the process, but I think the obtained probability says that with $~99\%$ chance indeed something have happened. I incorporated this into the question. Thanks you very much again.

Comment: I have found in Wikipedia the tool for verifying if something structural have change: [Principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis), but as shown in the page it look quite hard to implement on Excel (it remembers me the stages of implementing a Kalman Filter, which is indeed very hard to make it work on Excel)... Does anyone have experience on it? Its too hard for just this small dataset? maybe it don't make sense with these few points?

Comment: Here are 2 ideas- 1) split the data into before and after and compare means, or 2) run a regression with time (e.g. year) as a variable and see if time coefficient is statistically diff from 0.

Comment: @TickaJules Mean are different since the last 11 samples are below the average in a row. Also, I take a the betas of a [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) founding, as expected, that they have almost no influence, since things happened through time but not caused by the time variable (in physics laws is called "time invariant" $y(t)=f(x(t),t)=f(x(t))$). For the  overall data, the first 50 years, and the last 11 years their values are $\hat{\beta}_{61} \approx -0.0008;\,\hat{\beta}_{50} \approx 0.0002; \hat{\beta}_{11} \approx -0.0005$.

Comment: @TickaJules (...) Those numbers you were thinking about when you recommended doing a Regression?

Comment: In the first case (1) you need to figure out if the population means are different, which means the difference in the sample means is *statistically* significant (which has a precise meaning).  And for (2) I meant - see if the year (as a variable) is a meaningful variable in the regression.  Does knowing the year help you predict the energy value?  If so, then you can argue there's a time element here and something is changing.  So that involves looking at t-tests (not just beta hats).

Comment: @TickaJules I am quite rusty on Hypothesis tests, but If I didn't screw it, using the formulas from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_unequal_sample_sizes,_unequal_variances_(sX1_%3E_2sX2_or_sX2_%3E_2sX1)) I got a value for the degrees of freedom of $42$, so for an $\alpha = 0.01$ the following [table](https://cms.dm.uba.ar/academico/materias/1ercuat2015/probabilidades_y_estadistica_C/tabla_tstudent.pdf) show at $42 / 0.005 \approx 2.7$, and from the data the statistic is $T \approx 7.1$ so If a have get it right, (...)

Comment: @TickaJules (...) the Student's T test discard that the mean values of the previous 50 years could be equal to the mean of the ending 11 years (I think is ok due the difference between averages is greater than half the standard deviation of the samples). The issue with this attempts as it where just sample data is that the time variable of the process is ignored (same for a regression if I am not mistaken). For what I have search pattern change recognition is quite an issue in stochastic time series, as example, for deterministic series I remember from a control theory course the use wavelets

Answer (score 3):

[image: plot of data]

The last 11 years have very low ranks. If the data is such that every year is independently distributed, then there is a strong statistical significant effect that the recent 11 years are lower than the 50 years before that.

Asside from comparing the numbers above/below the mean (whose worst case give the p-value 0.000488) you could also use a rank test, which gives an even lower p-value.

```
    Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  y[1:50] and y[51:61]
W = 492, p-value = 4.686e-05
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

---

An important question is, "does it make sense to assume that the years are independent?".

Clearly the hypothesis that you have a steady state distribution where every year is independent is wrong. However, this does not need to mean that 'something structural have changed'. It can be that you have random fluctuations over larger time scales that influence multiple years. It can be normal to have longer periods of years that are high or low.

> or it is just too "cherry picking" as an assertion

This is always a risk with observational studies. Black swans happen and will be cherry picked.

More data, experiments, and theory can improve your believes.

> then the probability p=0.0488% is an upper bound for the "true probability", so considering all the years registered I have that at least with a probability of 99.95% something structural have change on the final 11 years.

The p-value indicates the probability of a type-I error (the probability of falsely rejecting the null hypothesis when it is actually true). It is not the probability that a certain effect is present.

Comment: thanks for answering. The probability I have used was $p=\frac{2^{50}}{2^{60}}=0.0488\%$ it is not the p-value, but instead what I think is the probability of having the **last 11 samples below the average in a row at the ending years** in 61 total points of a non-skewed distribution (under assumption the process is stationary). Does this change your analisis?

Comment: @Joako depending on how you formulate it, it can be a p-value. But in any way, you can not inverse it and state that 100% - 0.0488% is the probability that the alternative hypothesis is true.

Comment: mmm... sure I am mistaken, but I did't use it as a p-value, but as probability of having this trend just by chance: assuming the process is stationary (don't know if iid is also required), the probability should be ok, and is so low, that $1-p$ should tell it is not due just for chance, which ironically says also that stationary wasn't a good assumption, so something should have change over a stationary mean and variance assumption. As you said, maybe there is a underlying trend, natural or man-caused, it is highly probable the process is not stationary, (...)

Comment: (...) which I think somehow the $99.95\%$ is measuring... but I don't know how to proper measure there is a trend behind, or how to measure how non-stationary have been those last 11 years compared with the previous 51 registered years... I hope those numbers could be used as an upper bound, or maybe learn how to calculated a properly measure for showing there is a trend/change compared with the previous years.

Comment: By the way, I am still trying to understand your answer since I didn't know the test you have used: it was [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) or this [second one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test)?... surely the data is not independent by the way, since ice due snowfall of one year could be a saving of water for a previous year.

Comment: Damn man, that image resolution... (+1 irrespectively)

Comment: @usεr11852 I make those images on my mobile phone.

Comment: Savage (+1). I got to ask then: do you run R on your phone or you SSH? I have SSH-ed to a R server via my phone and I suppose I could try to make some plots but I never did.

Comment: @usεr11852 I use some online service, rdrr.io. The output is a square image and I wanted a 1:2 image so I splitted the layout in two. That caused the bad resolution. I would like to run R on my phone, but haven't yet had much need for it. The online possibilities are good and when they fail, then maybe I shoul use a real computer.

Comment: Agreed. Didn't know about that `rdrr` I will check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a two-part answer, the first part a direct answer to the question, and the second part a commentary.

Part 1: A simple, and exact, way to do it is to use the [Hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) distribution, as follows.

I am going to translate your problem into an "urn" model.  We have 61 balls, corresponding to the 61 years of observations.  32 of these balls are "above" the average, and 29 are "below" the average.  If I choose 11 balls without replacement - corresponding to the last 11 observations - what is the probability that they are all "below" balls?

The probability is easily calculated using any number of stat packages, or a calculator, as approximately $0.01\%$.

Part 2:  However, this isn't really telling you what you want to know, in a formal statistical sense.  To see this, consider whether you even would have done this test had, say, 5 of the last 11 observations been below the average, or what test you would have done if it had been the last 9 observations below average instead of the last 11 observations.  The fact that you observed what appeared to be a highly unusual result, then tested the significance of exactly that result, pretty much cancels out the value of the significance test - as it's based on "samples from a finite population that I think are highly unusual" rather than "random samples from a finite population" as the test calculation assumes.

In an informal sense, it's OK to say "I thought this was a highly unusual result, and it is!"  But it shouldn't be cited as a formal statistical test result.

Edit in response to comments:

To lend support to the validity of the Hypergeometric, I've constructed a simple example in code.  We have 61 observations, 29 of which are "below" and 32 "above".   We randomly rearrange them a million times, count the number of times that the last 11 observations have $0, 1, 2, \dots, 11$ "below" values, and compare to what the Hypergeometric distribution tells us to expect:

```
obs <- c(rep("above",32), rep("below", 29))

p0_to_11 <- rep(0,12)

for (i in 1:1e6) {
  x <- sample(obs)   # randomly rearranges the elements of "obs"
  nbelow <- sum(x[51:61] == "below")
  p0_to_11[nbelow+1] <- p0_to_11[nbelow+1] + 1
}

p0_to_11 <- p0_to_11 / 1e6

plot(p0_to_11 ~ c(0:11), type="b", pch=16, lwd=2, col=2,
     ylab = "Probabilities & frequencies",
     xlab = "# of 'below' observations")
lines(dhyper(0:11,29,32,11) ~ c(0:11), type="l", lwd=2, col=1)
```

[image]

The red dots indicate the observed frequencies, and the black lines are the Hypergeometric probabilities.  There would be red lines too, except that the black lines overlay them.  This is at least supporting evidence for the statement that the Hypergeometric is indeed the distribution to use in this circumstance.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Maybe I am mistaken, but if I am not the [Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) does not care about where the samples with the wanted characteristic are located within the data, so it doesn't take into account that the values here **are in a row** and also that the **this row is located at the end**, which reduce the amount of possible combinations that fulfill what those 11 samples **below the average in a row at the ending years** represent, giving an even lower probability. Hope you could comment if I am mistaken.

Comment: I am sorry to say you are mistaken.   If I select all 61 balls in a completely random order, the last, let us say, 11 selected are a sample drawn from the 61 balls.  The distribution of the number of "below" balls in this sample of 11 is Hypergeometric.  Similarly, the first 11 are a sample of 11 balls from the 61 (without replacement), and balls 11-22 are a sample of 11 balls...   You get to choose which 11 balls you are using as the sample, and as long as that choice is independent of the ball characteristics, you'll end up with a Hypergeometric...

Comment: Don't confuse the mechanics of the sample selection process with the statistical properties of the sample selection process (it's easy to do!).  The key here is that the last 11 balls wound up being the last 11 balls for reasons that have nothing to do with their values ("above" or "below"), at least under the null hypothesis.  Whether or not I arrange the balls in a row and choose the last 11 or just dump the last 11 into a bag is irrelevant.

Comment: As a probability stated as the number of favourable combination over total combination, I think it is relevant, since there are much more combinations of 11 sample of a row at any place than 11 in a row at the end (which have only one position for those samples). This is why mi intuition says is relevant.

Comment: No, there aren't more combinations of 11 in a row anywhere than at the end.   Pick any 11; you have one combination that's all "below", 11 combinations that are ten "below" and one "above", 55 combinations that are nine "below" and two "above", and so forth.  It doesn't matter whether they are the first 11, the last 11, the middle 11, or whatever.  Arbitrarily choose 11, for example, the last 11, and the number of "above" and "below" balls has to add up to 11, and the possible combinations are the same.

Comment: I disagree... it is different to pick without replacement that having a time series with final results below the average, just think in coin tosses: if $X$ means it could be heads (H) or tails (T), and I want the probability of having the last 11 coins ending tails in a row on a set of 61 coin flips, the favorable string is $XXX\cdots XXXXTTTTTTTTTTT$ which could happen only in $2^{50}$ ways, ruling out any combination of 11 tails that are not in the end like $XXX\cdots XXXTTTTTTTTTTTTX$,  $XXX\cdots XXTTTTTTTTTTTTXX$, etc.. which I believe are counted into the Hypergeometric dist. formula

Comment: I am really sorry to say you are wrong about this, and should think about it a little more.   You don't have 61 flips, you have a specific set of "above" or "below" results from the history of annual energy.  The question is, how likely is it that the last 11 are "below"?  And that is exactly the same as "how likely is it that, if I select 11 of the 61 observations at random without replacement, all 11 are "below""?   Which in turn is the same as "how likely is it, if I randomly rearrange the 61 observations , that the last 11 are "below""?   They are all the same and all Hypergeometric....

Comment: Read the  Wikipedia description of the Hypergeometric.  The probability that I calculated is that the final 11 observations are "below".  I do not understand why you think I calculated some probability involving, as in your last example, the final two observations being "X" (or "above".)   I drew 11 balls from the urn; these 11 balls correspond to the LAST 11 observations in your history.  I calculated the probability that all 11 are "below".

Comment: because being below or above the avg are 2 possibilities, so is like having head or tail in a coin flip. Since for the previous 50 samples I don't care about their values since I want to know just the combinations that have 11 values below the average in a row at the end, the last 11 values are fixed in just one chance (lets say Tails), and the previous 50 have two possibilities each (Head or Tails), so there are $2^{50}$ possible combinations fulfilling what I am asking over $2^{61}$ possible combinations. I think that the Hiperg. don't fit here because of the time variable.

Comment: The time variable is irrelevant, just as in your binomial example.  "The last 11 observations" is merely a mechanism for selecting 11 of the 61 observations.  The distribution would be the same if you selected the first 11 observations, the middle 11, or any fixed set of 11 observations.  The Hypergeometric solves precisely the problem you state - it gives the probability that, given 61 observations with 29 "below," the last 11 are all "below."  This is the same as the probability that the first 11 are all "below," the middle 11 are all "below," etc.

Comment: I have updated the answer with some supporting evidence.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest excel-friendly way to show the trend is to do a polynomial interpolation,

[image]

a more sophisticated version of this would be to use a digital filter.

However, apart from the approach @TickaJules suggested, I don't think there is a sensible way to define or interpret the probability of $11$ specific below-average data points.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I don't think an interpolation neither a moving average could show any trend with so few data. But I disagree with the interpretation of the 11 point below the average because this non-negligible fact: since the sample space is equilibratly weighted between samples above and below the average (it could be any other case, as a lognormal distribution as counter example), I think is valid to to think there is near a 50/50 chance to have a sample over or below the average. (...continues)

Comment: (...) Then, the probability has meaning because **it is not** "the probability of having 11 samples below the average", but instead, the "the probability of having 11 samples **in a row at the end**below the average", as for the examples of rows of coin tosses it change things a lot. But the problem are about if the interpretation I am doing is valid, which I don´t know (but it makes sense to me), but also if the probability is properly obtained, since in some websites I find different answers (like [this](https://apollo.neocities.org/math/runofheads.html) one)